# VBA - Copy last Row Formula to New row (Table)

Tags: excel, vba, listobject, excel-tables

looking for a code that will copy formula from Last Row to a new row in a table
or some code that make the new row with formulas :)

example: Last row number C25= A25+B25 so the new row Number 26 will take the formula and fit to the new row (will be C26 = A26+B26)

Thanks and hope to find the answer :)

Comment: Please note that SO is not meant as a 'can you please provide this code for me' repository. It is intended as a helpful resource for those that run into problems whilst working out their particular challenge?

Perhpas have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly** you can get the *last row number* `Last_row`, **then** you will copy the formula to the next cell row.

```
Dim Last_row As Double
Last_row = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Last_row).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Last_row + 1)
```

Comment: Seems almost like a solution !! but if i want few cells ? Different Cells like : O,N,H ?

Comment: Hi @dudi2s, if you have different cells in the same row to be copied you can just do as in "C" sample for other columns like "O", "N", "H". For example, ActiveSheet.Range("N" & Last_row).Copy ActiveSheet.Range("N" & Last_row + 1)

Comment: i tried but 1. if i take some cell with Formula its make "bottom title " not a row. 2. didnt make few cell together.. ..

Answer (score 0):

### Add a Row in a Table

- Adjust the worksheet and table names.
- All three codes do the same thing.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddRowInTableNoVariables()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add
End Sub

Sub AddRowInTableTableVariable()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    tbl.ListRows.Add
End Sub

Sub AddRowInTableAllVariables()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    tbl.ListRows.Add
End Sub
```